# Build a tree from a list of objects

Tags: python, list, data-structures, tree

I am trying to build a tree from a list of objects, which are characterised by several properties.
Each object can have 3 properties that play a role in building a tree, that is `velocity` `altitude` `exposure`.

```
#Data structure

class Test():
   pass

tests = []
for el in data:
   test = Test()
   test.velocity = el[0] #100km/h or 120km/h or 140km/h
   test.altitude = el[1] #20m or 40m or 60m
   test.exposure = el[2] #10uSv or 20uSv or 30uSv
   #more data is assigned which is not shown as irrelevant
   tests.append(test)

# I am trying to build a data tree like the one below.
# Obviously it would be different than this one and depend on actual data input.
# Example built statically using anytree

Tests
├── 100km/h
│   ├── 20m
│   │   └── 10uSv
│   ├── 40m
│   │   └── 10uSv
│   └── 60m
│       └── 20uSv
├── 120km/h
│   ├── 40m
│   │   ├── 20uSv
│   │   └── 30uSv
│   └── 60m
│       ├── 20uSv
│       └── 30uSv
└── 140km/h
    └── 20m
        └── 30uSv
```

Although this problem looks simple (might not be) I just can not figure it out.

Cheers!

Comment: It's not clear what you wand as output. Do you need to have resulting tree as `anytree` data structure? Or simple nested dicts or something else?

Comment: What is the meaning of the line relationship between two things like 100km/h and 20m? Is it like an edge?

Comment: @AlexKosh ideally it would be `anytree` so that it could be easily visualized. Nevertheless, I can't figure out how to do it via dictionary either

Comment: @RichardKYu this is a record of tests that were performed. Where velocity, altitude and exposure were experimental parameters. Each object has other data (not shown as irrelevant) which is the data obtained from that test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont provide original data, so I tried to guess them.

I started with constructing nested dicts and then converting them to `anytree` format with recursive function.

Here is the code:

```py
import itertools

import anytree

data = [
    ['100km/h', '20m', '10uSv'],
    ['100km/h', '40m', '10uSv'],
    ['100km/h', '60m', '20uSv'],
    ['120km/h', '40m', '20uSv'],
    ['120km/h', '40m', '30uSv'],
    ['120km/h', '60m', '20uSv'],
    ['120km/h', '60m', '30uSv'],
    ['140km/h', '20m', '30uSv'],
]

# Construct nested dicts
res = {'Tests': {}}

for a, b, c in data:
    res['Tests'].setdefault(a, {}).setdefault(b, {}).setdefault(c, True)

__import__('pprint').pprint(res)
# {'Tests': {'100km/h': {'20m': {'10uSv': True},
#                        '40m': {'10uSv': True},
#                        '60m': {'20uSv': True}},
#            '120km/h': {'40m': {'20uSv': True, '30uSv': True},
#                        '60m': {'20uSv': True, '30uSv': True}},
#            '140km/h': {'20m': {'30uSv': True}}}}


# Convert nested dicts to anytree format
def dict_to_tree(d, parent=None):
    if isinstance(d, bool):
        return

    for key in d:
        node = anytree.Node(key, parent)
        dict_to_tree(d[key], node)

root = anytree.Node('Tests')
dict_to_tree(res['Tests'], root)

for pre, fill, node in anytree.RenderTree(root):
    print(f'{pre}{node.name}')
# Tests
# ├── 100km/h
# │   ├── 20m
# │   │   └── 10uSv
# │   ├── 40m
# │   │   └── 10uSv
# │   └── 60m
# │       └── 20uSv
# ├── 120km/h
# │   ├── 40m
# │   │   ├── 20uSv
# │   │   └── 30uSv
# │   └── 60m
# │       ├── 20uSv
# │       └── 30uSv
# └── 140km/h
#     └── 20m
#         └── 30uSv
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Alex. Though here seems to be a problem in it, as your data has two objects of `120km/h and 40m` but in a tree only one of it is visible

Comment: I fixed that error, so, please, accept answer if it was helpful

Comment: I would expect tree to looks like this based on your `data`:

 Tests
 ├── 100km/h
 │   ├── 20m
 │   │   └── 10uSv
 │   ├── 40m
 │   │   └── 10uSv
 │   └── 60m
 │       └── 20uSv
 ├── 120km/h
 │   ├── 40m
 │   │   ├── 20uSv
 │   │   └── 30uSv  #this one is not on your tree but is in your data
 │   └── 60m
 │       ├── 20uSv
 │       └── 30uSv  #this one is not on your tree but is in your data
 └── 140km/h
     └── 20m
         └── 30uSv

Does this make it clearer?

Comment: Thanks, now it does exactly what I wanted! Good to know too where the error was coming from

Comment: I replaced `res['Tests'].setdefault(a, {}).setdefault(b, c)` to `res['Tests'].setdefault(a, {}).setdefault(b, {}).setdefault(c, True)`. And modified condition to stop recursion